# What's the last number in my wordy number sequence?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence, computer-puzzle, sequence

I have a wordy number sequence, partially shown below:

$ {1, 45.2548, 1262.6650, 32768, 390625, 10077696, 282475249, 3037000499.976, 31381059609, ... }$

Can you find the last number in the sequence?

Hint 1:

> Look at the tags! Doesn't one seem odd?

Hint 2:

> Look at the adjectives! Doesn't one seem odd?

Hint 3:

> If you solve this puzzle, you will get 15 (power)points towards your reputation!

Comment: Why "wordy"????

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison See my comment on the answer below...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Complete Solution:**

The numbers can be rewritten as:

> $1=1^k$
>  $45.2548=2^{5.5}$
>  $1262.6650=3^{6.5}$
>  $32768=4^{7.5}$
>  $390625=5^{8}$
>  $10077696=6^{9}$
>  $282475349=7^{10}$
>  $3037000499.976=8^{10.5}$
>  $31381059609=9^{11}$

Therefore, the $n$-th term should take the form of:

> $n^x$

By **Hint 3**,

> The author hints that the powers are actually consecutive font sizes in Microsoft Word! **Thanks to @shoover in the comments for discovering the connection to font sizes! Also credit to @Stiv for finding the link between "Word" and MS Office first, though it was actually the hint gave it away to me.**
>  The list of font sizes in the dropdown menu, in increasing order: 5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8 9 10 10.5 11 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 36 48 72 (largest font size in the dropdown menu).

Therefore, the last term is

> the 21st term, and is equal to $21^{72}$ aka 158412417187039737963434604385921446947320760732675527347603818345931941295685218431561257343841

**With that said, though, it should be noted:**

> There are actually two versions of list of font sizes in the dropdown menu! The version the @Ankit used seems to be extremely uncommon. The more common version, which is 8 9 10 11 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 36 48 72, is much more widely used. With this more common list of font sizes, it would have been impossible to spot the pattern!
>  
>  Here is the screenshot of Word 2007 with the list of font sizes used in this problem ([Source](https://jingyan.baidu.com/article/72ee561ab1ec33e16138dfbe.html)):
>  
>  [image]

Comment: good start; wasn't expecting anyone to catch the math so quickly. All the information needed is already there. Tbh I gave more terms than you would need. Pay attention to the words written there. Also be aware that you are supposed to find the last number, not the next one.

Comment: I'm guessing the mathematical pattern followed quickly from a chance factoring of the integers present?

Comment: Nice answer. To complete the solution we may look for hints in "wordy", but also in the fact that non-integers terms have not been rounded in the same way (I don't know whether it is relevant).

Comment: @Feryll That's right.

Comment: @Evargalo Idk, but my guess is that it's for the purpose of calculation. For example, my calculator outputs log3(1262.6650) to be exactly 6.5 (due to precision limits), so it is easier to see the pattern above.

Comment: @Evargalo the rounding in the same way is not relevent. The 5.5,6.5,7.5 and 10.5 is correct. I just put 4 digits after the decimal.

Comment: @Feryll Its not about factoring.

Comment: @Ankit : for 3037000499.976 , you put only three digits after the decimal. I reckon it has no signification for solving the puzzle, but I wonder if there really is much more to find out than what Jerry has already shown. If there is any logic for picking 11.5 or 12, I am afraid it will just be an arbitrary choice...

Comment: @Evargalo There are three digits because the fourth was a 0. I made the puzzle and I am quite certain that it is not just an arbitrary choice. Pay attention to the wording of the puzzle it will give you a hint...

Comment: Hey @JerryDean - a hunch tells me that the answer may have something to do with the number of bytes or bits required to store a given number (computer-puzzle tag and the arbitrary number of decimal places chosen). I'm too lazy to check, and in either case, I want you to be awarded the correct answer for your great observations.

Comment: @JerryDean, a quick Google search yielded some more evidence in favor of the bytes/bits idea https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

Comment: @user75502 Nice idea! But the author said that the number of digits is not an arbitrary choice in the comments above, so it seems like this might not be the right way to go?

Comment: @user75502 Personally, I feel that the odd tag is the sequence tag, which shows that it's not just a number sequence. However, I've had several hypothesis, but they are all too far-fetched and consist of no more than 9 terms... That's why I'm kinda stuck right now.

Comment: I feel like the pattern is something painfully obvious but I simply can't put my finger on it... :(

Comment: @JerryDean I meant appearing arbitrary or otherwise arbitrary. The choice wasn't arbitrary in the sense that he consciously added decimal places to take up more space and maintain the pattern.

Comment: @Jerry The OP made the "arbitrary" comment in regards to "any logic for picking 11.5 or 12", not to the number of decimal places. In fact, earlier comments suggest that the decimal places are irrelevant for the final solution, which would make sense since it's probably only got to do with the x^y forms. If I had to guess, "wordy" probably means there are 26 numbers in the sequence, representing the alphabet.

Comment: The latest hint confirms a hypothesis I've held for a while - this is somehow connected to MS Office ('wordy' = Word). However, version numbers and release years aren't leading me anywhere. How else can we derive numbers from it?

Comment: @Stiv sbag fvmrf?

Comment: @shoover That sounds pretty promising! I don't know why, but my Word doesn't have that with .5, but I'm sure I've definitely seen that as a font size before. I just need to find out where...

Comment: @JerryDean , Dude you are so close but thats not it... its not powerpoint that you should be looking in...

Comment: well done you are correct

Comment: Just saying, I wouldn' t call it "a serious flaw." First of all I have the latest version of Word, second even if the solver didn't have that version they could look up different versions... there are enough hints that it is ms word.

Comment: @Ankit I would agree that it's not a serious problem, but I did feel kind of frustrated while solving this, because at one point I was literally looking at every text editor available on the Net to find this list of fontsizes. Also, I think it's not a version issue, because I've seen screenshots of different word versions with either version of font sizes. Plus, it's actually quite difficult to look up the different versions (it could be that I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: @Ankit Anyways, this puzzle's quite creative. Nice one!